# How to fix the quality of MP4 videos on ubuntu

Tags: video, video-player, mp4

so I have gnome-restricted-extras but just look at this

[image]

How can I fix this

I know I can use vlc but why is this happening is there any solution to it?

I have latest ubuntu version updated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with hardware video acceleration since kinetic. What graphics does your system have?

For nvidia `sudo apt install nvidia-vaapi-driver`

Intel 8th gen and above `sudo apt install intel-media-va-driver-non-free`

That fixed it on the two computers I have. For older intel try installing intel-vaapi-driver, I do not have AMD to troubleshoot but it may be similar.

Comment: i have intel 4th gen cpu i3-4005u and graphic is integrated HD 4400 pls give me solution for this

Comment: Try the last one I mentioned, `sudo apt install intel-vaapi-driver`